# CakePHP2系にてURLからコントローラーに引数を渡したい

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP2系で投稿機能で投稿した記事にコメントできる機能を実装しています。

DB上ではCommentテーブルのPost_idカラムに投稿した記事のPostテーブル上のPost_idと同じ値が入るようにしたいです。また、PostとCommentの二つのモデルは`public $hasMany = "Comment";`でリレーションが作れています。現状はURLまでpost_idの値が反映されているのですが、コントローラー側で受け取ることができていない状態です。

**ビューファイル**

```
<td>　
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Comment',array('controller'=>'comments',
                                                 'action'=>'comment',    
                                                 $post['Post']['id']))?>
</td>
```

**コントローラー**

```
<?php
class CommentsController extends AppController {
    public $helper = array('Html','Form');

    public function comment($post_id)
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $data=$this->request->data;
            $id=$this->request->params['post_id'];
            $data['Comment']['post_id']=$post_id;

            if ($this->Comment->save($data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Success!');
                return $this->redirect('/comments/comment/');
                //$this->Comment(array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'view', $this->data['Comment']['id']));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('failed');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 貼られたコードは`{}`の数が合わないように思います。必要な部分が抜け落ちていないか確認してみてください。

Comment: コードがなぜか枠内に収まらないのですが、一応修正しました。また、commentアクションを起動しようとするとToo few arguments to function CommentsController::comment(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expectedと引数が足らないとエラーが出てしまいます。しかし、どこが間違っているか見つけることができません。。。

Comment: `/comments/comment/1` にブラウザでアクセスしても同様のエラーとなりますか？

Comment: /comments/comment/id番号のように入力するとコメント投稿フォームページに行くのですが、そこから送信を押すと最後のid番号（パラメーター 部分）が消えて、先ほどと同じエラーが出現します。

Comment: コメントト投稿フォームのViewテンプレートを提示してください

Comment: routesファイルに直接引数を設定しすることでなんとかidのパラメータをコントローラー側で取得することに成功しました。まだ、データベースエラーが出てしまっているので、そこを直さなければならないですが。。。（笑）

Comment: 以下のコードをコントローラーに追加することで解決いたしました。if(isset($post_id)){
$data['Comment']['post_id']=$post_id;
/////////ビューから値を取得
if ($this->Comment->save($data))
{
$this->Session->setFlash('Success!');